# How to add dynamic row in custom module magento 2

Tags: custom, dynamic, dynamic-rows, custom-admin-grid

I have created the adding dynamic row entity in config module,
here is the snap shot for same,
[image]

Now i want the same functionality while i am adding or editing the form through admin grid .
Please check the snapshot of form,
[image]

If anyone know the solution please let me know,this will be huge help
Thanks in advanced